# How to recursively find all ipynb files in a directory, and why does my bash code fail

Tags: bash, macos, syntax, find

```
#!/bin/bash

directory= /Users/sakshamgupta/Downloads/Automation-TCN/Data
for var in $(find $directory -type f -name "*.ipynb")
do
    echo "${var:2}"
done
```

I am trying to read all ipynb files in a directory and subdirectory. The script gives the error below

```
./convert-ipynb-py.bash: line 3: /Users/sakshamgupta/Downloads/Automation-TCN/Data: is a directory
find: illegal option -- t
```

Comment: you shouldn't have a space after `=` when assigning `directory`.

Comment: How did I miss that, thank you so much!